# iOS 11 style navigation bar height back port to earlier OS?

Tags: ios, uikit, ios11

Is there any way to mimic the higher navigation bar shrinks when pushed effect in earlier OS?

I've tried override :

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size{
    CGSize result = [super sizeThatFits:size];
    result.height += self.heightDelta;
    return result;
}
```

and change heightDelta dynamically, but it doesn't work. Latter values are not used by UIKit.

Comment: Try to specify the frame in `layoutSubviews`, too.

Comment: *- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGSize size = [self sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
}*   I've tried layout subViews like this, and the frame did change. However, one more problem comes. the animation does not animate with top layout guide, so when animation the content below the bar have no animation and will become black if the bar height shrinks.